# How to find an address by a hex value in string format?

Tags: c#, winforms, binary, hex, byte

I have a `int key1 = -1466731422;` which returns me the hex value `62 74 93 A8` from the .exe when I search for it in a hex editor.
What I'm trying to do is to overwrite a `newKey1`, which can be choosen by the user, over that `key1`.
Supposing we want to overwrite that `key1` for `int newKey1 = -1566731422`, what I did so far is:

```
private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FixHex(key1, newKey1); //transform the int key in hex string

    br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(element.FileName));            
    try
    {                
        for (long i = 0; i <= br.BaseStream.Length; i++)
        {
            if (br.BaseStream.ReadByte() == (byte)Convert.ToInt32(key1, 16))
            {
                progressBar.Value = progressBar.Maximum;
                br.Close();
                bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(element.FileName));
                bw.BaseStream.Position = i;
                bw.Write(newKey1);
                bw.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Key updated", "Success");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                progressBar.Value += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

It didn't work, tho. My `for` loop doesn't find a match, so what I think it will solve it's a method to find the address by the `int key` (since in a hex editor I can do it) OR by a hex in string format.

Comment: You're comparing only one byte instead of the whole key.  That will cause many false positives.

Comment: @itsme86: Both sides of the comparison are just a byte, one via reading just one byte, the other via casting away the higher bits.

Comment: @BenVoigt my `FixHex` method returns to me:
`string key1 = "0x627493A8"` and `string newKey1 = "0x62939DA2"`

There's another way to compare it with the `ReadByte`?

Comment: I don't know if helps, but I also have a list that contains each hex pair... like: `627493A8` :: pairHex[0]  = 62;
pairHex[1] = 74;
pairHex[2] = 93;
and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you're looking for an integer value (which takes four bytes), there's  no need to read a single byte. Directly read an integer using the `BinaryReader` overload that takes an `Int32` value and see whether it matches the one you seek.
2. You're trying to write a string. It's not a string, it's a sequence of four bytes in little endian. You need to write these four bytes to replace those existing.

[BinaryReader.ReadInt32()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readint32?view=netframework-4.7.2) advances the stream position by 4 bytes, so you need to keep track of the reading position, incrementing it by 1 for each read and setting the `BaseStream` position *manually*.

Using **`FileAccess.ReadWrite`** and **`FileShare.ReadWrite`** for both the `BinaryReader` and the `BinaryWriter`, you can find the value and overwrite it in one go:

Note: there are no means to validate a possible false positive here, for lack of informations on the file structure. That's up to you.

```
int valOriginal = -1466731422;
int valSubstitute = -1566731422;
int valLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(valOriginal).Length;

using (var reader = new BinaryReader(
    File.Open("[File Path]", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))) {
    int position = 0;
    while (position < (reader.BaseStream.Length - valLength))
    {
        reader.BaseStream.Position = position;
        if (reader.ReadInt32() == valOriginal)
        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(
                File.Open("[File Path]", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))) {
                writer.BaseStream.Position = position;
                writer.Write(valSubstitute);
            };
            break;
        }
        position += 1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, you're not comparing the correct things in the correct way.
The way you want to compare the things you're comparing depends on the format of the data you are reading in the BinaryReader and the type of "key1".

In your description, you say "key1" is an int, but then try to convert it like its a string.  I'm just going to assume its an int. You can leave a comment if that is not correct.

The format of the data in your file is also not clear from the description.  I'm going to assume it's ints.  If its not ints, add a comment. Reading an integer looks like:

```
int testVal = br.ReadInt32();
```

This gives you an int and because both are ints, you can just compare as ints:

```
if(testVal == key1)
{/*do your other stuff*/}
```

It's probably better to loop while not the end of the file rather than looping over each byte, something like:

```
while(br.BaseStream.Position != br.Basestream.Length)
```

Putting it together might look something like:

```
while(br.BaseStream.Position != br.Basestream.Length)
{        
    int testVal = br.ReadInt32();

    if(testVal == key1)
    {/*do your other stuff*/}
}
```

Another note: Because you're 'new'ing the BinaryReader each time this method called and the BinaryReader is closed in the 'if', you might consider a `using` around your BinaryReader and declaring there as well.  This will ensure that the BinaryReader is disposed of properly in the case of an exception.  The below variation will allow proper disposal of the BinaryReader but still catch any exception (also, its kind of frowned upon to catch the general Exception):

```
try
{
    using(var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(element.FileName)))
    {
        while(br.BaseStream.Position != br.Basestream.Length)
        {        
            if(br.ReadInt32() == key1)
            {/*do your other stuff*/}
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Hope that helps.